# What "innocent" work as in this context in relation to two paragraph

Tags: meaning-in-context

> And that's pretty much how I imagined it; what I never imagined is that the future reader might look back on any of this, or on my own peculiar experience, and say, "How quaint." How ***innocent***. **Not for a moment did I suspect that the financial 1980s would last for two full decades longer, or that the difference in degree between Wall Street and ordinary economic life would swell to a difference in kind**. That a single bond trader might be paid $47 million a year and feel **cheated**.—*The Big Short: Inside the Doomsday Machine* by Michael Lewis—

Hello, I had few questions after I read this paragraph and it might need more context to be answered, so I had linked below for book preview that has paragraph quoted.

My first question is, first, why the word "innocent" wouldn't have been what author have imagined and second, why and who have gotten paid $47 million(because I can't find anyone referred here) and why feel "cheated".
Third, I might ask what the sentence that is in bold would mean so does it have to do with his author calls it "innocent"?

Here's book preview for previous context: [The Big Short](https://books.google.com/books?id=erDXCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT12&dq=And+that%27s+pretty+much+how+I+imagined+it%3B+what+I+never+imagined+is+that+the+future+reader+might+look+back+on+any+of+this,+or+on+my+own+peculiar+experience,+and+say,+%22How+quaint.&pg=PT12&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=And%20that%27s%20pretty%20much%20how%20I%20imagined%20it%3B%20what%20I%20never%20imagined%20is%20that%20the%20future%20reader%20might%20look%20back%20on%20any%20of%20this%2C%20or%20on%20my%20own%20peculiar%20experience%2C%20and%20say%2C%20%22How%20quaint.&f=false)

Comment: Final result of sentence structure I figured?(someone tell me if this is correct): "Not for a moment did I suspect.." sentence introduces the reason why his future reader, looking back in his book about him expects them to be surprised by bond market affairs done in 80s, calls it—affairs I just mentioned in parenthesis and this is for future reader who doesn't understand underlying meaning of any word like me—"innocent" with following sentences start with "that" which adds more horrible things happened two decades later

Comment: I think you have it now.

Comment: Thanks! your feedback helped me very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[American Heritage Dictionary *innocent*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=innocent)

> a. Not experienced or worldly; **naive**.

[American Heritage Dictionary *naive*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=naive)

> 1. **Lacking worldly experience and understanding**

Apparently, someone has told the author that they think him quaint and **innocent** because he is surprised at the excesses of those times. He is thought to be **innocent** because it surprises him that someone who gets paid 47 million dollars in one year might still feel **cheated**. They felt cheated because they thought they should get even more.
(The individual who got paid that much is some bond trader. Such things were not uncommon.)

This comment is in the prologue to a book, and the author is describing comments that he received about a book that he wrote earlier.

Comment: Oh, I see, also "Not for a moment did I suspect.." sentence would mean that  "not becuase if he expected those" but surprised at things like person got 41millions?

Comment: That means that when he wrote the first book, he didn't suspect that the period of financial excess would last 20 years, and that the gap between the rich and the ordinary people would become so great. It was part of his innocence that he did not suspect that.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry if it bothers but I wondered several sentences after "Not for a moment..." sentence all start with "That" so I'm wondering what that implies—I expected matching result with previous paragraph or something grammatic form that I don't know.

Comment: No problem. "That" is a conjunction used to introduce a subordinate clause. It is repeated because it introduces multiple clauses. Here is a more compact example of the same thing:  I did not suspect that she was gone... that she had left me... that I would be alone forever.

Comment: Got it. This answer explained to me all that I wondered haha :)